# Fast linq query with join and count

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq

I have this SQL query witch is running fast if executed from TOAD in Oracle database where Jobs table contains more than 2 million records.

```
select * from Technicians  A
left join  
  (select TechnicianCode,count(*)JobCount from Jobs 
   where TxnCode in ('Jc','Jcd') group by TechnicianCode) B
on B.TechnicianCode =A.TechnicianCode
```

Not able to translate it to linq in efficient way.
Can anybody help with it?

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Comment: Noted. I am newbie to LINQ My efforts always missed something like left join or generating count and it is very slow. @SAJ and Vojtěch Dohnal answers I was able to get what I need efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
var txnDetails =  from job in jobs
                  where job.TxnCode == "Jc" || job.TxnCode == "Jcd"
                  group job by job.TechnicianCode into g
                  select new { TechnicianCode = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
```

Then you can just do normal select with join

```
 from technician in Technicians
 join txn in txnDetails on technician.TechnicianCode equals 
   txn.TechnicianCode into tg
 from t in tg.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new {Count = t==null? 0: t.count, ...}
```

Comment: I tested it and it is running fast but how to make it left join? thanks

Comment: group clause ok but left join?

Comment: Just wondering if this could be achieved using one expression without a hepler variable txnDetails, perhaps using `into` clause... Tried it briefly but without success.

Answer (score 1):

To do the left join, modify @SAJ answer like this:

```
var result =  from technician in Technicians
   join txn in txnDetails on technician.TechnicianCode equals 
    txn.TechnicianCode
   into j 
   from lj in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select lj;
```

Comment: where group statement

Answer (score 0):

Is this you're looking for?

```
var result = from technician in Technicians
                join job in Jobs on technician.TechnicianCode equals job.TechnicianCode into A
                from job in A.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where job.TxnCode == "Jc" || job.TxnCode == "Jcd"
                select new 
                {
                    Tech = technician,
                    Job = job
                };
```

To get the count you can simply use:

```
var count = result.Where(r => r.Job != null).Count();
```

Comment: it is not working and I can not see where it will generate count?

Comment: Why not? Did you get any error? For count you can select job as well and get count out of it. See my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

It try Code:

```
var result= (from  p in Technicians            
             join q in Jobs.where(c=>c.TxnCode=="JC" || c.TxnCode==c."Jcd").GroupBy(c=>c.TechnicianCode)
             .Select(m => new { jobcount = m.Count(), TechnicianCode = m.FirstOrDefault().TechnicianCode,  TxnCode=m.FirstOrDefault().TxnCode}).ToList()             
             on p.TechnicianCode equals q.TechnicianCode into jj from kk in jj.DefaultIfEmpty() 
             select new {    
                          jobcount=kk.jobcount,  
                          TxnCode=kk.TxnCode, 
                          TechnicianCode=p.TechnicianCode 
                        }).ToList();
```